# How to check jenkins is installed in centos or not?

Tags: jenkins, centos7

how to check **Jenkins** is installed in **centOS7** or not?

Is there any command for that?.

Thanks!!

Comment: And also how to see the version of jenkins..

Comment: i tried **which java** command it shows java path / **which mvn** it shows maven path /but for jenkins i tried **which jenkins** it shows no jenkins in those locations. but i installed jenkins by this command **sudo yum install jenkins** and it shows complete. anyone tell me what should i do for installing jenkins and to start it

Comment: I would suggest you combine your comments into your question.

Comment: Will `rpm -ql jenkins` work?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian yes it shows so many locations of jenkins

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to your `/var/lib/jenkins/` there will be a file called `config.xml`

View that file `cat config.xml` and there should be a xml entry called:

```
<version>YourVersionNumber</version>
```

Or on the Jenkins home screen when it is running click the About button and you will see the version number there.

The generic start up for Jenkins is:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

Which can be found [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins)

Comment: Thanks..first my jenkins works well.Dont know what happened, today it fails to start. so i reinstalled jenkins,but i think i did something wrong in my jenkins installation...because no files are there inside /var/lib/jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

As you've installed it through yum, this command should do

```
sudo service jenkins status
```

This one also (it's the same):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins status
```

If they return a missing file error, e.g. something like

```
env: /etc/init.d/jenkins: No such file or directory
```

, it's not installed - at least not through a package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Just give

```
sudo service jenkins status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using following command

```
jenkins-lts --version
```